# Non-FUSE drivers for NTFS and exfat

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, fuses, exfat

I've run long benchmarks about write speed on a USB3 external HDD on a RPi4 (goal: use it as a NAS), with and without encryption.

I've noticed that write speed is very fast with `ext3`, `ext4`  (it can reach the limit of the HDD speed, i.e. ~ 100 MB/sec without encryption and ~ 50 MB/sec with VeraCrypt AES encryption), but it's quite slow with `ntfs` or `exfat`. But I still need NTFS or exfat because of the requirements of my project.

Note: `ntfs-3g` and `exfat-fuse` both use FUSE

Question: how to use:

- **non-FUSE NTFS drivers**, for example the new open-source Paragon NTFS3 driver (see https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs3-driver-faq/#table_h)
- **non-FUSE exFAT driver**, for example Samsung exFAT driver (https://www.linux.com/news/samsung-releases-exfat-utils-to-format-file-system-fsck/)

on a Raspberry Pi?

---

Note: here are tables that show how massive the improvement could be when moving from `exfat-fuse` to other ones: https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux

Comment: Have you approached Paragon as the first offers a trial that you sign up for (note it may be a commercial offering) and the second link states GITHUB is where the code is so I would start there...  AS for speed - are you bottle necked?  Have you seen https://youtu.be/oWev1THtA04 ?

Comment: *"how to use"* -> It's the same as building and installing any kernel module.  What some of the instructions (eg. from the exfat github page) don't properly explain is that "This will install the module to your currently running kernel" *if* you have the right build environment, which requires (at least part of) the source for your current kernel: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html  Doing that on a pi is not quite as simple as on a standard Debian etc., but you should be able to find oodles of pi-specific explanations here and elsewhere.